# Placing the cursor at the top left of a vertically stretched TextField?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a page through which the user can create a note for my Notes app. This is my build method so far:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Note"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.save,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField (
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "Title",
                ),
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: TextField (
                    expands: true,
                    maxLines: 25,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

This is how the page looks right now. How do I ensure that the cursor of the second TextField is placed at the top left and make said TextField stretch to fit the remaining height?

[image: This is the output I'm getting.]

Answer (score 2):

You should set the textAlign property of the TextField to start

```
textAlign: start
```

Edit:

based on @Andy_519's and community input please use the following

```
textAlignVertical: top
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction, I had to set textAlignVertical to Top to fix my issue.

Comment: This should be added as an answer @Andy_519

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tolga-kartal and @Andy_519, I there was one thing missing:

```
textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top
```